# Transform Coordinates from Mercator to Local Coordinate System using ProjNet

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, mapbox

What i am trying to accomplish is essentially i have a mapbox static image, and i'm trying to project from the center of that map to a local coordinate system.

So i have the center longitude and latitude, and the center is also at (0,0) in the local coordinate system, but when trying to move an object that is associated with a GPS coordinate i cannot figure out how to implement projNet to convert from Mapbox's EPSG:3857 to a local coordinate system using ProjNet.

The goal is to make it look like the object is moving around on the static image map.

The documentation is severely lacking https://projnet.codeplex.com/ and their FAQ skip key steps in which i cannot reverse engineer to figure out what they are doing.

I would even accept more pseudocode on what needs to happen, i am just not able to figure this out.

Comment: I have also tried some linear algebra and essentially solving for the conversion between two coordinate systems, but it does not work for more than one point. (I do the math, and it successfully moves the object to the correct location, but doesn't do it for other locations)

Comment: What is the local coordinate system? Do you have a WKT (well-known text) / prj file for it? Or the EPSG well-known ID (WKID)?

Comment: @mkennedy the local coordinate system would be a Cartesian coordinate system, but if i can get it to Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) then i can get meters and make that transformation.  So essentially: I'm getting GPS lat,lon in WGS84, and i need to project that into (EPSG:3857), but actually setting up a coordinate system for (EPSG:3857) is not clear due to lack of documentation.